# Definition of post-composing for homotopy classes of maps

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

The set of homotopy classes of maps from $X$ to $Y$ is
denoted by $[[X, Y]]$. An element
of $[[X, Y]]$ is denoted usually by $[[f]]$.

Given a map $\alpha : Y \to Z$, there is a function $\alpha_* : [[X, Y]] \rightarrow [[X,Z]]$ defined by post-composing with $\alpha$, viz., $f \rightarrow \alpha \circ f$.

Can someone explain an example of this? I can't see how the map $f \rightarrow \alpha \circ f$ maps between the two equivalence classes. How would you write $\alpha_{*}([[f]])$ with this composition relationship? Is it $[[\alpha \circ f]]$? This isn't explicitly explained in the book I'm reading.

Comment: Yes, that's how it's defined.

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I've reworded your question to get rid of the phrase "homotopy equivalence classes of maps" as it could be interpreted as the collection of homotopy equivalences from $X$ to $Y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, $\alpha_*[[f]] = [[\alpha\circ f]]$.

Let $\mathcal{C}(X, Y)$ denote the set of continuous functions $X \to Y$. There is a quotient map $\pi : \mathcal{C}(X, Y) \to [[X, Y]]$ given by $f \mapsto [[f]]$.

If $\alpha : Y \to Z$ is a continuous map, there is an induced map $\alpha_* : \mathcal{C}(X, Y) \to \mathcal{C}(X, Z)$ given by $f\mapsto \alpha\circ f$. If $f$ and $g$ are homotopic, then so are $\alpha\circ f$ and $\alpha\circ g$, i.e. if $[[f]] = [g]]$, then $[[\alpha\circ f]] = [[\alpha\circ g]]$. Therefore the map $\alpha_*$ descends to a well-defined map $[[X, Y]] \to [[X, Z]]$, again denoted by $\alpha_*$, given by $[[f]] \to [[\alpha\circ f]]$. This is represented in the commutative diagram below

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathcal{C}(X, Y) @>{\alpha_*}>> \mathcal{C}(X, Z)\\
@V{\pi}VV @VV{\pi}V \\
[[X, Y]] @>{\alpha_*}>> [[X,Z]].
\end{CD}$$

Comment: So the same symbol $a_*$ is being used to represent two different maps?  The first being continuous functions and the second being equivalence classes?

Comment: Yes, this is the case in my answer.

Comment: So by saying post composing it's referring to the continuous maps, from which we derive the equivalence class maps through the diagram?

Comment: Exactly. The key point here is that if $f$ and $g$ are homotopic, then so are $\alpha\circ f$ and $\alpha\circ g$. This is why the induced map on equivalence classes is well defined (or said another way, why the diagram commutes).